# «Так вот(,) как они это называют». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, частицы

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении? Как правильно?

1. Так вот, как они это называют.
2. Так вот как они это называют.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так вот как они это называют.
Так вот почему их ватниками называют!
Так вот как это называется.

Запятая после "так вот" не нужна. В ["Справочнике по пунктуации"](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=708) Розенталя говорится:

> **Так вот**
> ...
> 2. *частица + частица*. Сочетание частиц усиливает
> значение последующих слов. Между частицами "так" и "вот" знаки
> препинания не ставятся.
>
> *Так вот куда искал дорогу таинственный солдат!* Л. Кассиль, Кондуит и Швамбрания.

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос. Там в другом месте сомнения. Нужно использовать такое правило из Розенталя: "Не ставится запятая после выделительных частиц **вот, ведь**, стоящих перед подчинительным союзом в придаточных предложениях, предшествующих главному, например: *Хвастаться пока особенно нечем, вот как пятилетку...*"

Comment: Так здесь нет никакого придаточного предложения — предложение-то простое! "Сочетание частиц усиливает значение последующих слов". Просто усиливает. Зачем же тут запятая? А пример "из Кассиля" и "мои" предложения это подтверждают.

Comment: Да, я что-то не то написал, извините. Но и Ваш ответ я прочитал так, будто Вы объясняете отсутствие запятой между "так" и "вот".

Comment: КАК же написать, чтобы было "еще понятнее"? Ведь это "выдержка" из правила — я ничего не изменяла. ЧТО (какую информацию) надо добавить?

Comment: Я не догадался, что это выдержка из правила. Если Вы не возражаете, я оформил её как цитату. Ответ я поддержал, извините и не серчайте :)

Comment: Спасибо большое — вот теперь совсем правильно и красиво. Жаль только, что словарная ссылка исчезла.

Comment: Ой, я это не нарочно. Вернул ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Я сначала думал, что это вводное слово, однако нет: частицы ими не являются. Это не сравнение (не можем задать вопрос к частице). Я думаю, что в данном предложении "так вот" - междометие, которое указывает "как они это называют".

Из двух частиц главная, мне кажется, - "вот", потом - "так". Вот - указательная частица. По Д. Э. Розенталю частица "вот" не обособляется.

Возможно, я не прав.