# ТАК ВОТ с местоимениями

Tags: семантика, частицы

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка! В предложениях типа:

1. Так вот кто ворует мои яблоки.
2. Так вот куда он тратит деньги.
3. Так вот почему он не ушел.

частицы "так" и "вот" независимы или "так вот" - это единая частица? Какую смысловую нагрузку несет сочетание "так вот" в вышеуказанных предложениях?

Comment: NEO, на сайте принято благодарить участников за их ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх. Тот ответ, который был наиболее полезным и решил проблему, отмечается еще и галочкой как принятый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похожий вопрос про частицу **так вот** уже задавался на форуме.
[«Так вот(,) как они это называют». Пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453589/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F?rq=1)

Но в нём рассматривались, в основном, предложения с "как". Мне кажется, что можно дать дополнительную информацию.

[**Так вот**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_708), *частица*
Не требует постановки знаков препинания частица «так вот» в сочетаниях с относительными местоимениями («где», «кто», «куда»...) в восклицательных предложениях.
***Так вот где** таилась погибель моя!* А. Пушкин, Песнь о вещем Олеге. *Жилище философа! **Так вот где** он проводит бессонные ночи в размышлениях.* В. Дудинцев, Белые одежды.
[Пометка: в книге есть восклицательный знак ([ссылка](https://books.google.ee/books?id=XGlwAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT222&lpg=PT222&dq=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85.&source=bl&ots=xmIXGH1jrt&sig=ACfU3U0IDu8mffFtbmYf9qI_gY1b8bVlOw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVjb7Roe_uAhXGvosKHfHwCeoQ6AEwA3oECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85.&f=false)).]

Стоит, думаю, дополнить ряд относительных местоимений:
что, какой, каков, чей, который, сколько, когда, откуда, почему, как, зачем, отчего.

**Так вот** состоит из двух частиц — такое сочетание усиливает значение последующих слов.

...ему уже кажется, что он это видит, что это ясно, ― и рассуждение заключено словами: "так это вот как было, так вот какой народ нужно разуметь, так вот с какой точки нужно смотреть на предмет! " [А. А. Зализняк. Лингвистика по А. Т. Фоменко // «Вопросы языкознания», 2000]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Многие частицы усиливают значение слов. В данном случае что усиливается?

Comment: Я думаю, что конструкция **так + вот** — это своеобразный симбиоз двух частиц. _Вот_ (обычно) — указательная частица (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82); _так_ (обычно) — усилительная (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA). Получается, что одна из частиц указывает (**Вот** кто ворует мои яблоки), а другая — усиливает это указание (**Так вот** кто ворует мои яблоки!). В конце такого предложения всегда хочется поставить восклицательный знак. P. S. Приветствую Ваше желание разобраться.