# Расстановка запятых в предложении

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая после "вот"?

*А вот как это происходит у меня!*

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите ответ V. Lilla на [похожий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453589/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). У вас не "так вот", а "а вот", но тут происходит такое же ***усиление** последующих слов.*

Можно сказать нейтрально:

> (А) у меня это *вот так* происходит.

А можно выразительнее, как у вас:

> *А вот как* это происходит у меня!

***А*** у нас говорит о том, что это ответная реплика, придаёт ей выразительности:

*— У меня так.

— А у меня во́т как!*